# grails one to many with additional column

Tags: grails, relationship, one-to-many

In my Grails project I need to have a 1:N relationship between two domain classes. So, I've created the following domain class:

```
class Receipt_HealthService {

   Receipt receipt
   HealthService healthService
   int quantity = 1

   static constraints = {
     }
}
```

and in Receipt I have the following:

```
 @NotNull
static hasMany = [healthServices:Receipt_HealthService]
```

So a new table is created that has got the id of both domain class and the `quantity` field.

When I call the save() method everything works well, but when I call the update() something does not work.

If user modifies the Receipt, removing one of the HealthService previously saved, and modifying the others, older HealthServices remain saved with the new ones. For example:

Receipt 1 created with :

- HealthService 1 with quantity = 2
- HealthService 2 with quantity = 3

Modification of Receipt 1:

- HealthService 1 deleted
- HealthService 2 modified with quantity = 2
- HealthService 3 with quantity = 1

After the update() I have the following:

Receipt 1 with:

- HealthService 1 with quantity = 2
- HealthService 2 with quantity = 2
- HealthService 3 with quantity = 1

I suppose that this behaviour is because of adding the new domain class. Do I maybe add manually the correct saving of HealthService in update()?

EDIT:
the previous problem about save() is solved changing the code. I was using a method that is no more useful in my code. That method uses receiptInstance that, at the moment of method calling, is not filled with data and so I had the exception in save().

Comment: What do your params contain ? Also, why are you creating the Receipt_HealthService class, and why did you put a @NotNull on top of hasMany ? That's not how you create a one to many relationship in grails. See https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#oneToMany and the not null constraints should go in the constraints closure. See https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#constraints

Comment: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/domain/grails/plugin/wschat/ChatUser.groovy as an example

Comment: I've created the Receipt_HealthService class because I need to add the extra column quantity to the relation, and I think this is the only way to do it. About the @NotNull you are right and I will change it, but the problem remains

Comment: @vahid for what the sample given is useful?

Comment: sorry I thought it had the line number - look at photos has many then look at line 24 - nullable:true set in contraint as pointed out by philippe's comments above. That was a generic point about your post that Philippe had pointed out. The actual issue will be in his first part of the question was in in your params - simply do println params before that save to view what is being attempted to be saved. if (!b.save()) {
    b.errors.each {
        println it
    }
} https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html to find out what it is not saving

Comment: I've edited the question showing params value. about the relationship, maybe I need to add the belongsTo inside HealthService domain class, because I want that each Receipt has 1 or more HealthServices, and I do not want that user can delete HealthService if it belongs to a Receipt. about nullable, maybe must be false for my case.

Comment: about my previous comment, belongsTo is not needed, because it adds the receipt id to HealthService table, and I want that an HealthService could be used for 0 or more receipt. I need to understand how to solve the empty instance issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue with the following code. I hope that someone gives me a comment about it.

```
receiptInstance.healthServices.collect().each {
        //I've tried to use receiptInstance.healthServices.clear()
        //but Set remains with all items 

        //delete item from Set
        receiptInstance.healthServices.remove(it) 
        //delete item from DB
        it.delete()
    }

         //save with flush to commit the delete
    if (!receiptInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [receiptInstance: receiptInstance])
        return
    }
```