# grails foreign key error in delete parent row

Tags: grails, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following situation:

```
class Receipt {

   BigDecimal totalAmount;
   Date releaseDate;

   @NotNull
   Integer vatPercentage;

   @NotNull
   Integer discount;

   Boolean isPayed;
   Boolean isInvoice;
   Boolean hasStampDuty;

   Integer documentNumber;

   @NotNull
   static belongsTo = [patient:Patient, doctor:Doctor]

   @NotNull
   static hasMany = [healthServices:Receipt_HealthService]


    static constraints = {
        healthServices(blank:  false)
        patient(blank: false)
        totalAmount(blank: false, )
        vatPercentage(blank: false, nullable: false)

    }


}


class HealthService {

   int vat;
   String description;
   BigDecimal price;

   static belongsTo = [healthServiceType:HealthServiceType, doctor:Doctor]

   static constraints = {
      healthServiceType(blank: false)
      vat(size: 11..11)
      description(maxSize: 255)

    }
}  


class Receipt_HealthService {

   Receipt receipt
   HealthService healthService
   int quantity = 1

   static constraints = {
   }
}
```

I've manually created the Receipt_HealthService domain class, as described in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954545/grails-one-to-many-with-additional-column).
Everything works well, but when I try to delete a Receipt instance, I see the following error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`my_localdb`.`receipt_health_service`, CONSTRAINT 
`FK96DE98B9D3292D2C` FOREIGN KEY (`receipt_id`) REFERENCES `receipt`(`id`))
```

Why do this happen? Why the Receipt_HealthService instances are not automatically deleted? What do I need to change to allow the automatic deletion and remove the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `Receipt_HealthService` doesn't have a `belongsTo`, therefore `Receipt`'s deletions are not cascaded. See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#cascades .

You can either change `Receipt_HealthService` as following:

```
class Receipt_HealthService {
   ...
   static belongsTo = [receipt: Receipt]
}
```

Or try to define the cascade behaviour explicitely (see http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customCascadeBehaviour).

Another posibility is to add a `beforeDelete` to `Receipt` that takes care of deleting each entry in `healthServices`. See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping

For this last option, you can check the classes `User`, `UserRole` and `Role` from the `Spring Security Plugin` as an example. I didn't find a sample project online, but you can just install the plugin in a sample project and run `grails s2-quickstart` to see how the `User#beforeDelete` looks like (see https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/ref/Scripts/s2-quickstart.html).

Comment: Thanks! Do the belongsTo add a field into Receipt table?

Comment: A field? I don't think so. Semantics for accessing the relantionship from both sides will be the same (receipt.healthServices and receipt_HealthService.receipt). DB wise it should also be the same: receipt_health_service should have a FK called receipt_id.